# Unable to load Kernel module "uio:

Tags: 14.04, kernel, modprobe

I am using a Ubuntu-14.04 server image. I want to load kernel module name "uio" but I am getting the following error.

```
sudo modprobe uio
modprobe: FATAL: Module uio not found.
```

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo lsmod` by editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

You 1st need to install the package.

the correct name is: [uio-module-drv-dkms](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/uio-module-drv-dkms).

---

It is in the [canonical partner PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/canonical_partner?dist=trusty) so you have to add the PPA with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ vivid partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list'
```

prior to installation.